# Why can you eat raw oat flour but not raw wheat flour?

Tags: baking, flour, raw

I see recipes that use [raw oat flour](https://thegirlonbloor.com/healthier-edible-cookie-dough/#recipe). But I have read that eating raw wheat flour causes samonella. What is it about oats that allows you to eat them raw?

Comment: People have been eating cake & cookie dough for centuries

Comment: It’s actually been e.coli, not salmonella that’s been the issue with raw wheat in recent years.  (And I thought it was listeria before that).  And I suspect that much of the problem is when the wheat from many farms are brought together and mixed, so one field with animal poop on it could contaminate many tons of flour.